# Java reserved type name "var" best practices?

Tags: java, var, java-10, effective-java

Unfortunately, there is no item in Effective Java that discusses the reserved type name "var"(since it is introduced in java 10).

There is a saying to use interfaces as types whenever you can (**Item 64: Refer to objects by their interfaces**). But When using `var`:

`var list = new ArrayList<String>(); // infers ArrayList<String>`

(`list` is of type `ArrayList<String>`)

Effective Java states It is a bad practice to refer to a variable by its implementation because It makes code dependent on it.
This is just one annoyance I've found when starting to use var in my code.

#### Question:

Are there any best practices when using the reserved type name "var"? When should I use It? When should I avoid it?

Comment: Read the [guidelines here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html)

Comment: [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-10-local-variable-type-inference) is another blog for clearing up the basics.

Comment: You can check also the official Java doc related to java10 (Local-Variable Type Inference) support 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/language/toc.htm